# Sonar: IllegalStateException

Tags: maven-3, sonarqube

I am trying to setup sonar on Ubuntu 12.04 machine. However, when I run `mvn` (maven 3.0.4), it fails with this exception. The sonar server is running fine, I can access it from browser.

Here is my sonar profile in settings.xml (~/.m2/settings.xml)

```
<profiles>
 <profile>
  <id>sonar</id>
  <activation>
     <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
  <properties>
     <sonar.jdbc.url>jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar</sonar.jdbc.url>
     <sonar.jdbc.driver>org.h2.Driver</sonar.jdbc.driver>
     <sonar.jdbc.username>sonar</sonar.jdbc.username>
     <sonar.jdbc.password>sonar</sonar.jdbc.password>
  </properties>
 </profile>
</profiles>
```

Exception:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project configurator: Can not execute Sonar: IllegalStateException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal     org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project configurator: Can not     execute Sonar
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Can not execute Sonar
at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:118)
at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.start(Bootstraper.java:65)
at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:90)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
at org.sonar.home.cache.FileCache.newTempFile(FileCache.java:143)
at org.sonar.home.cache.FileCache.get(FileCache.java:83)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.PluginDownloader.downloadPlugin(PluginDownloader.java:53)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchPluginRepository.doStart(BatchPluginRepository.java:74)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchPluginRepository.start(BatchPluginRepository.java:65)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1002)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:760)
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:72)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Container.start(Container.java:71)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:88)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:72)
at org.sonar.maven3.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:142)
at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:113)
... 23 more
```

Let me know if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack trace told us that the current plugin is `org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0` which is quite old, since 05-Nov-2011.

I would like to recommend ***not to define it in our pom.xml*** as mentionins at [Analyzing with Maven: Recommended Way](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Maven#AnalyzingwithMaven-RecommendedWay) as the following:-

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests=true
mvn sonar:sonar
```

> skipTests=true not to run unit tests twice: during the install goal and again during the sonar goal. You can also deactivate the integration tests execution. Please refer to the Maven documentation.

Anyhow If you would like to define it explicitly, please use the latest one which is matched with your Sonar server version. e.g. I'm using the current Sonar server version 3.5. The plugin should be either, `org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:3.5` or `org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:3.5`

Even the [Installing and Configuring Maven](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+Maven) also told us that the `sonar.host.url` is an optional (the default is `http://localhost:9000`), I also would like to encourage to define it explicitly as well.

I hope this may help.

Comment: Thanks. I am now using sonar plugin version 2.5 and it worked.

Comment: `mvn compille` should be good enough, I'd not recommend install even though it's only going to be local repo